# C: scanf("%d", ...) with the input only a minus sign

Tags: c, scanf

I tried the following code (compiled with GCC 13, on Ubuntu 22.04)

```c
int x;
int ret = scanf("%d", &x);
char ch;
scanf("%c", &ch);
printf("%c, %d\n", ch, ret);
```

with the input

```
-*
```

It prints `*, 0`, which suggests that the first input to `x` failed (the return value is `0`), but the first minus sign was consumed. This also happens when I change the minus sign to `+`, but not for other characters.

Is this sign treated as the beginning of an integer? If so, why this input is seen as failure? If not, why is it consumed? Or is this totally undefined behavior?

Plus, the same thing happens for `double` when the input is `.`.

Comment: The `scanf` function is *greedy*. In other words, it will consume all characters as long as there might be a match. If there's no match, the characters it has consumed are lost. This is one reason I always recommend using `fgets` instead, and pair it with e.g. `sscanf`. And you should *always* check what any `scanf` family function returns.

Comment: The `scanf()` family of functions only puts back one character on a parse failure.  After reading the dash, it fails on the asterisk and puts that back.  The dash is lost forever.  The `sscanf()` function allows you to try multiple times.  This is one (of many) reasons to prefer it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is the greediness required by the standard, or is it just what is observed on common implementations?

Comment: It's what the standard mandates — see C11 [§7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function ¶9](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p9).

Comment: Besides the question I marked this as a duplicate of, I suspect, based on vague memory, there is another Stack Overflow with further discussion, but I am not finding it at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this sign treated as the beginning of an integer? If so, why this input is seen as failure? If not, why is it consumed? Or is this totally undefined behavior?

The following applies from `fscanf()`:

> An input item is read from the stream, ... . An input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence.<sup>348</sup> **The first character, if any, after the input item remains unread.** If the length of the input item is zero, the execution of the directive fails; this condition is a matching failure ... .
> C23dr § 7.23.6.2 9

> <sup>348</sup> `fscanf` **pushes back at most one input character** onto the input stream. Therefore, some sequences that are acceptable to
> `strtod`, `strtol`, etc., are unacceptable to `fscanf`.

As I read this, with OP's input of `"-*"`, it wasn't until the `'*'` was read that `scanf()` realized the input matching failure and push the `'*'` back into `stdin` (as required by the spec.).  *Some* systems will successfully push back the `'-'` also (note that the footnote itself is informative - not a spec.), but OP's system did not.

Moral of the story:
`(f)scanf()` is difficult to use with faulty input.  Instead for *line* input, use `fgets()` to read the line into a *string* and then parse the string.

---

Note that optional leading white-space characters (with `"%d"`) are also consumed.

Note there are longer input sequences such as `"-.*"` for `"%f"` which cause trouble.

Comment: `"-INFINITx"` might be a longer bad input for `"%f"` that would be nice to have it push back the `"INITx"` to just consume `"-INF"`.

Comment: This has been discussed at more length previously—There is a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: A good [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78127727/c-scanfd-with-the-input-only-a-minus-sign/78129668?noredirect=1#comment137742633_78129668) for under the question and then to VTC as a duplicate once the dupe is found.